# Voximplant: sharing a certain window in Voximplant

Tags: voximplant

I use Voximplant and couldn't find answer in the docs. How do I share not the entire screen but a certain window in Voximplant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shareScreen method, and then in the browser dialogue choose the entire screen or a separate window.